# How to handle situation when error happens during posting form from view user control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewusercontrol

I have a view user control that can post form. This control can be used on multiple views. 
If user enters invalid data i add errors to ModelState - as simple as that. The problem is 
that i don't know which view/actionresult to return since i don't know from where user post form. Ok, i can get urlreferer - but that does not look nice for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the info from your parent page to the controller.

```
<% RenderPartial("MyUserControl", new MyUserControlViewData()
{
    // pass parent page info here for user control to redirect to such as
    Controller = "Home",
    Action = "Index"

   // or even better
   ParentPath = ((WebFormView)this.ViewContext.View).ViewPath
});
```